# Unable to insert record in database in zend?

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, zend-db-table

I am using following tutorial:

http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/learning.quickstart.create-model.html

When I try to insert record in database something like this:

```
$userModel = new Model_User_Object();
$userModel->setFirstName( 'FirstName' );
$userModel->setLastName( 'LastName' );
$userModel->save();
```

I am getting following error:

```
No entry is registered for key 'Logger'
```

Thanks

Comment: That looks nothing like the quickstart tutorial. What is `Model_User_Object()`? Does it extend anything? What's in the `save()` method?

Comment: `Model_User_Object` is extended by another class that contains `save()` method. `save()` method is working fine for other tables. The problem is above error for this specific case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error is usually thrown by `Zend_Registry` when you try to `get()` an index that is not registered. I guess in your model you're doing something like `Zend_Registry::get('Logger');` ? Have you already registered 'Logger' in the registry?